# How to attach pen tool to endpoint of a segment in Geogebra?

Tags: geometry, math-software

How to attach pen tool to endpoint of a segment (or curve) in Geogebra such that by moving segment, the pen draw a curve? for example I want to draw animated [Cycloid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid) in Geogebra but I don't know how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a point leave a trace as it moves by checking the box show trace:

[image: geogebra show trace box]

Sorry, I don't have it in English. I used [the online geogebra tool](https://www.geogebra.org/classic).

**EDIT:**

There is also a command called *Locus*. And this is actually a better way since tracing doesn't give you a continous curve.

From the manual:

> Locus[Point Q, Point P]
>   Returns the locus curve of the point Q, which depends on the point P.
>   Note: Point P needs to be a point on an object (e. g. line, segment, circle).

So, if your movable point is $A$ and the point to trace is $B$, type *Locus[A,B]* into the console and you get the curve for the point $B$ as $A$ moves along its curve.

Comment: wooo. that works. but after zoom out or zoom in the trace disappear. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: I didn't know before but I read about the Locus command from here: http://research.shu.ac.uk/geogebra/GIS_Guides/Official%20GeoGebra%20Manual.pdf I'll edit that to my solution.

Comment: That is wonderful. many many thanks.

Comment: @C.F.G You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pen tool, you can also build the curve yourself using the Curve command.

For example, following commands create a cycloid with the circle.
How much the cycloid is join is controlled by the Slider T. After
you customize individual elements through the GUI, turning
animate on T will give you an animated cycloid.

```
X(t) := t - Sin[t]
Y(t) := 1 - Cos[t]
T : Slider[0,4*Pi,0.1,1]
A : (T,1) 
B : (X(T),Y(T)) 
s : Segment[A,B] 
c1 : Circle[A,1] 
ca : Curve[X(t),Y(t),t,0,T] 
cb : Curve[X(t),Y(t),t,T,4*Pi]
```

Comment: if the origin curve is not a circle then we cannot  use this method.